# Date filter in hive while doing left outer join

Tags: sql, hadoop, join, hive, hue

I am doing a query build in hive, the query is given below.

*

```
Select * from CSS407 
LEFT OUTER JOIN PROD_CORE.SERV_ACCT_ISVC_LINK SASP
ON CSS407.TABLE_ABBRV_CODE = 'SACT'
AND CSS407.EVENT_ITEM_REF_NUM = SASP.Serv_Acct_Id
AND to_date(CSS407.EVENT_RTS_VAL) >= SASP.Acct_Serv_Pnt_Strt_Dt
AND to_date(CSS407.EVENT_RTS_VAL) <  SASP.Acct_Serv_Pnt_End_Dt 
LEFT OUTER JOIN PROD_CORE.CUST_ACCT_SA_LINK ASA
ON CSS407.TABLE_ABBRV_CODE = 'SACT'
AND CSS407.EVENT_ITEM_REF_NUM = ASA.Serv_Acct_Id
AND CSS407.EVENT_RTS_VAL_UTC_DTTM >= ASA.Acct_Relt_Strt_Dttm
AND CSS407.EVENT_RTS_VAL_UTC_DTTM <  ASA.Acct_Relt_End_Dttm
LEFT OUTER JOIN PROD_CORE.CUST_SA_LINK ASAT
ON CSS407.TABLE_ABBRV_CODE = 'TACT'
AND CSS407.EVENT_ITEM_REF_NUM = ASAT.Serv_Acct_Id
AND CSS407.EVENT_RTS_VAL_UTC_DTTM >= ASAT.Acct_Relt_Strt_Dttm
AND CSS407.EVENT_RTS_VAL_UTC_DTTM <  ASAT.Acct_Relt_End_Dttm
```

*

When I am executing the above table in hive I am getting the below error

**"Both left and right aliases encountered in JOIN 'SASP'"**

On further investigation I founded that we cannot use date between filter in the join on condition. In every post everyone is asking to insert that filter in where condition.

But in our case if we are moving that date between filter to where condition then we are not getting any data since left outer join is not satisfying.

I am getting this issue while executing in HIVE, it is working fine in Teradata and oracle

Please help.

Comment: Please share the real SELECT clause (It is probably not `Select *`) because there are probably other ways to solve it other then using multiple LEFT JOIN

Comment: P.s. I assume you get a single record from each joined table?

Comment: Do you have primary keys for your joined tables?

Comment: I am facing this issue while executing it in HIVE, if we are executing the same query in Teradata it is working

Comment: This is a Hive limitation. If you'll answer my question I would probably be able to supply you with a work-around.

Answer (score 0):

Only equality(=) works in join condition in Hive.Move **<=** to where clause.

I have the similar issue earlier.Please check below thread.

[Hive Select MAX() in Join Condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42352767/hive-select-max-in-join-condition)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

There might be some common column between CSS407 and SERV_ACCT_ISVC_LINK which might be creating this error.

Comment: no, since we are taking select * it will not create any issue also we have provided aliases for all the columns